# Исключить при FTP публикации удаление конкретных файлов а так же их публикацию

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core при публикации FTP с параметром "удалять все существующие файлы при публикации" я хочу чтобы например файл web.config не был удален, а так же не хочу чтобы он был включен в публикацию после удаления всех файлов. Пытался указывать в .csproj разные параметры которые рекомендуются в интернете но все равно не получается по причине того что не нахожу нужный мне ответ. Заранее извиняюсь за простенький вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Официальная документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles): Исключение файлов

Вам нужно вручную модифицировать xml-профиль публикации, добавив секции `<MsDeploySkipRules>`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFile">
    <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
    <AbsolutePath>Views\\Home\\About1.cshtml</AbsolutePath>
  </MsDeploySkipRules>

  <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFile">
    <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
    <AbsolutePath>Views\\Home\\About2.cshtml</AbsolutePath>
  </MsDeploySkipRules>

  <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFile">
    <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
    <AbsolutePath>Views\\Home\\About3.cshtml</AbsolutePath>
  </MsDeploySkipRules>
</ItemGroup>
```